# Debug Oracle stored procedure using Toad

Tags: oracle, debugging, toad

I have the following situation:
I have a java code launching a stored procedure. What I want is to launch the java code, and when arriving into the stored procedure, to start debuggin it using Toad.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it is not possible. The code will be executed in the session of the Java-Code, not in your Toad session.

**EDIT:**
Writing some trace in your application might be sufficient to track down the problems.

**TOAD Debugger:**
Looks like you need a special license, have a look at [asktoad](http://www.asktoad.com/DWiki/doku.php/faq/answers/editor#why_is_the_bug_icon_and_my_debugger_toolbar_disabled) which lists the possible reasons if the menu is disabled.

If your license allows debugging, this [article](http://www.bestremotedba.com/toad-debug-option-not-enabled-for-oracle-10g-database/) might be interesting to allow debugging with Oracle 10.

Comment: I mean, is it sufficient for you to debug the procedure by calling it from Toad?

Comment: Yes, I think is good enough.....
To use Toad in Debug mode, I need a Toad with a special licence?
Because my Toad, have the DEBUG menu disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle offer their own IDE, SQL Developer, which - usually for Oracle - is free.  I know you probably don't want to install two IDEs on your desktop but I mention it because it supports debugging of PL/SQL procedures.  [Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/sqldev_obe/plsql_debug/plsql_debug.htm).

It is possible to use DBMS_DEBUG by hand but I wouldn't advise it unless you have a lot of time and patience.  Oracle intended it as an API for tool vendors rather than something for real people.

Bear in mind that however you initiate a debugging session you need an account with the DEBUG CONNECT SESSION and DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE privileges.

Comment: Can I temporarily sprinkle an oracle SP with some sort of print statements then? Where would those show up? Can this output be redirected to a file? Is it better to create a table instead?